# Why I am getting this error "access violation writing location"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to write a c++ program to read some data from a file. My code is:

```
void read_file(const char *foldername) {
    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    const char *filename;
    filename=strcat((char *)foldername, "L1_matrix");
    fp=fopen(filename, "w+");
    if(fp)
        while (fgets((char *)c,512,fp))
            printf("%s", c);
}

int main() {
    read_file("A:\\Project\\Root\\event_1\\");
    getchar();
}
```

I want to read several files like L2_matrix etc.

But in this I am getting several error like:

1. Access violation location error(I found this error  I get in filename)
2. The variable 'c' is being used without being initialized.

If anybody can help it will be a great help.

Comment: if you're using C++, why not use c++ I/O and string functions?

Comment: @TomTanner: Because they are perfectly fine still, and sometimes even better?

Comment: @Deduplicator For I/O I'll agree, but not for string functions.

Comment: Your `char c;` should be `char c[512];`.

Answer (score 1):

```
strcat((char *)foldername, "L1_matrix");
```

`strcat` takes an in-out parameter pointing to a buffer containing a 0-terminated string, and big enough to store the result, and a pointer to a string.

You give it `foldername` and assure it that it actually points to a modifiable buffer by casting.
**Don't lie!**

Similarly for your second error, but the cast is more egregiously wrong:

```
fgets((char *)c,512,fp)
```

This reads the *uninitialized* variable `c`, thus your "without initialization"-warning, which is UB.
Next, you forcibly convert it to a `char*`, but never fear: On modern desktops, writing or reading through an integer in the `char`-range converted to a pointer will segfault.

Comment: so what you suggest that I need to use for correcting the first error

Comment: @lya: Allocate enough space (see `strlen`, and don't forget the 0-terminator) with `malloc` (don't forget to `free` it later like you forgot to `fclose` the file), and assemble your new string there. Though you are in C++, so using `std::string` would be preferable, as it's harder to get wrong.

Comment: Actually I am new in this c++ and I really dont know how to use malloc. std::string I tried and I am getting error like 'string unidentified'.If you can edit my code that will be really helpful for me.